# How to hide a section in Crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have 5 `sections` that don't always have data, i want to hide the `sections` that are empty. I read some posts i found online saying something about `formula` but i don-t know how to do it nor where to start.

```
if {@yourformula}="1" then
    true 
else
    false
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps :

- Go to Expert Section
- Select your Section
- Check the suppress checkbox on the right
- Click the formula button right next to the checkbox label
- Now on the formula editor to write your logic

Write something like this :

```
if {@yourformula}="1" then
    true //hide
else
    false //don't hide
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i spent hours looking for this feature, i was about to give up "^^

Answer (score 1):

Go to section expert and select which section you want to suppress, then select the suppress (no drill down) check box.

if you want to hide the section when the section is blank, select the suppress blank section check box

Answer (score 0):

Or simply turn on the checkbox for '***Suppress Blank Section***'.
It is located 3 positions below the Suppress checkbox.